# LocalToGlobal Multiple Times

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

For whatever reason this code does not work properly. Could someone be a fresh pair of eyes and find what I'm doing wrong? I honestly have no idea what is the matter. Here is the code:

```
import flash.geom.Point;

var upperPoint:Point = new Point(monster.animation2.upper.attackMarker.x,monster.animation2.upper.attackMarker.y);
var animationPoint:Point = new Point(monster.animation2.upper.localToGlobal(upperPoint).x,monster.animation2.upper.localToGlobal(upperPoint).y);
var monsterPoint:Point =new Point(monster.animation2.localToGlobal(animationPoint).x,monster.animation2.localToGlobal(animationPoint).y);
var globalPoint:Point = new Point(monster.localToGlobal(monsterPoint).x,monster.localToGlobal(monsterPoint).y);

trace(globalPoint);
```

Here is a quick diagram of the parental relationships among the movieClips:

monster[ animation[ upper[ attackMarker ] ] ]

Flash should trace the exact point at which the `attackMarker`would be if I were to take the movieClip out of all its parents. Could somebody figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting to find a display object's global coordinates, you only need to call `localToGlobal` *once* on the object's direct parent (in your example, monster.animation2.upper):

```
var attackMarkerPoint:Point = new Point(monster.animation2.upper.attackMarker.x, monster.animation2.upper.attackMarker.y);
var globalPoint:Point = monster.animation2.upper.localToGlobal(attackMarkerPoint);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I've never globalized a point through multiple nested parents before. God bless you!